# MinGW stdio.h : No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c, windows, gcc, mingw

i know that there are some other posts with this problem but the solutions that where given weren't helpful for me.
I just installed MinGW on my Windows 7 laptop.

So i wrote a hello world program to try the compiler but when i compile it i get this message: hello.c:1:20: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
   #include 
compilation terminated.

I don't know what to do,i have installed mingw on c directory and changed the path to mingw's bin. i use the command gcc hello.c -o hello to compile and the code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
main() 
{
printf ("Hello,world\n");
}
```

Any suggestions ?
Thank you.

Comment: you could explicitly set the include path: `gcc hello.c -I<path-to-you-include-dir> -o hello` - if that solves the problem, then you just need to specify the right environment variable for the include path.http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html

Comment: @Ashalynd: No he should not.

Comment: Something is wrong with your MinGW installation. In Command Prompt run: `g++ -E -x c++ - -v < nul` and update your question with the results. Furthermore, update your question with detailed information on where exactly MinGW is installed and how do you invoke `gcc` (i.e. do you rely on the `PATH` environment variable?).

Comment: I also use MinGW - the one that comes with the Code::Blocks 12.11 distribution. It's installed in c:\program files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW. When I hit build in the IDE, the command that is actually executed is: `mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall  -g    -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include"  -c C:\Users\enhzflep\Documents\code\schedTmp-deleteMe\main.c -o obj\Debug\main.o` - setting th PATH variable as you have done only ensures you can 'see' the files in the MinGW\bin folder - you still have to specify the include and lib folders in the command, as Ashalynd said.

Comment: @Haroogan Thank you for your answer. I did what you said and i uploaded a print screen to see by yourself the results http://postimg.org/image/87ekaq4wz/ MinGW is installed at c directory ( C:\MinGW ) ..to invoke gcc i just do : cd c:\mingw\bin and then gcc hello.c -o hello NOTE: i have the hello.c file in the mingw's bin

Comment: Do you actually have `stdio.h` in `C:\MinGW\mingw32\include`? Check it, so that we are sure before doing anything.

Comment: @Ashalynd i tried that and it messaged me this: Access Denied

Comment: @Haroogan ...no actually it is not there..

Comment: Hahaha, see... Your MinGW installation is totally broken. Get fresh MinGW-w64 distributions for the designed addressing (32-bit/64-bit), threading (POSIX/Win32), and exceptions (SJLJ/DWARF/SEH) from **[here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/)**. Test it, and if it works, I'll summarize it all as an answer.

Comment: @Haroogan but it is here: C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\ssp
here: C:\MinGW\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\ssp
here: C:\MinGW\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\tr1
and here: C:\MinGW\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\tr1

Comment: Yes it should be there too, but if you look carefully at your own screenshot, you will see that these directories are not searched by default for standard includes, and they are not supposed to be searched. The one `stdio.h` that you need (and it's a bit different from the ones you are showing above) should definitely be in `C:\MinGW\mingw32\include`, and if it's not there, then your MinGW distribution cannot be trusted anymore.

Comment: I guess there might be something wrong with permissions. May be you installed MinGW as admin and haven't permitted anyone else to use it? (Just guessing). In any case, reinstalling it looks like the easiest fix.

Comment: @Haroogan ok thank you very much for your time! i don't understand why it is broken,i downloaded it from the official mingw's website...anyway i will do what you said in your previous answer!